# Setting up a database, schemas, tables and stored procedures all in one click

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file

I have all the scripts to do:

1. Set up a database.
2. Create schema/s.
3. Create tables.
4. Create stored procedures.

I would like to write a batch file that will have SQL Server run those scripts and consequently my database will be created easier and quicker. For the sake of this example, lets assume that I have a folder with the address `C:\folder` and inside this folder I have files `SetDatabase.sql`, `SetSchema.sql`, `SetTable.sql`, and `SetSP.sql`. How would I set all that up on localhost\TSQL2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in powershell using [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

```
sqlcmd -S serverName\instanceName -i scripts.sql
```

The above statement will execute a script.

You can use the :r [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) in another file (scripts.sql) to store all your scripts.

```
:r C:\..\script1.sql
:r C:\..\script2.sql
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set _connectionCredentialsMaster=-S MyServer\MyInstance -d Master -U sa -P mypassword 
set _connectionCredentialsMyDatabase=-S MyServer\MyInstance -d MyDatabase -U sa -P mypassword 
set _sqlcmd="%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"


%_sqlcmd% -i MyFileCreateDatabase001.sql -b -o MyFileCreateDatabase001.Sql.log %_connectionCredentialsMaster%
%_sqlcmd% -i MyFile001.sql -b -o MyFile001.Sql.log %_connectionCredentialsMyDatabase%
%_sqlcmd% -i MyFile002.sql -b -o MyFile002.Sql.log %_connectionCredentialsMyDatabase%




set _connectionCredentialsMaster=
set _connectionCredentialsMyDatabase=
set _sqlcmd=
```

Just remember, when you run the 'Create Database' statement, you are actually USING the "Master" database.  Then, after MyDatabase is created, you can use it.  Thus why the first line in the example above...connects to Master.

The above will let you set the credentials "at the top" "one time"....and keep your lines in the file for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL data tools to implement your needs. You should study about that before you do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/tools.aspx